# Rails: finding a record by a combination of related records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a Ruby on Rails 4 app, consider this data model:

```
Question:
  id: int
  # [...]
  has_many: Answers

Answer:
  id: int
  question_id: int
  # [...]
  belongs_to: Question
  has_many: Results through AnswerResult

AnswerResult:
  id: int
  answer_id: int
  result_id: int

Result:
  id: int
  # [...]
  has_many: Answers through AnswerResult
```

Using this model, consider this behaviour:

1. There are multiple questions, all having multiple answers.
2. Each specific combination of answers leads to one and only one result.

Now, here is my question:

After the user has answered all my questions, I end up having a hash of question IDs with the user's answer IDs. I want to find the result that belongs to that combination of answers.

How do I do that?

---

EDIT: Example: (as requested in comments)

Questions and answers, and their IDs

```
Gender:     [Question #1]
  - Male    [Answer   #1]
  - Female  [Answer   #2]
Age:        [Question #2]
  - < 30    [Answer   #3]
  - 30 - 65 [Answer   #4]
  - > 65    [Answer   #5]
```

Results:

```
Junior man   [#1]  bound to answers [#1, #3]
Senior man   [#2]  bound to answers [#1, #4]
Old man      [#3]  bound to answers [#1, #5]
Junior woman [#4]  bound to answers [#2, #3]
Senior woman [#5]  bound to answers [#2, #4]
Old woman    [#6]  bound to answers [#2, #5]
```

Input:

```
{ 
  1 => 2, # Gender: female
  2 => 4  # Age:    30-65
}
```

Function finds the result bound to answers #2 and #4

Output: `Result #5: Senior woman`

Comment: Could you put an example of input and desired output?

Comment: Done. My example only mentions 2 questions, but the function obviously should work with more as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult problem to resolve in SQL unless you know about the concept *[Relational Division in SQL](http://gregorulm.com/relational-division-in-sql-the-easy-way/)*.

The following query provides you the expected result

```
SELECT results.*
  FROM results
  INNER JOIN answer_results 
    ON results.id = answer_results.result_id
  WHERE answer_results.answer_id IN (2, 4)
  GROUP BY results.id
  HAVING COUNT(results.id) = 2
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8784b/17)**

Here you are a non-tested (you might change something) possible solution in ActiveRecord

```
answer_ids = input.map(&:last)

Result.joins(:answer_results).where("answer_results.answer_id IN (?)",
 answer_ids).group('results.id').having('COUNT(results.id) = ?', answer_ids.size)
```

Comment: This looks like the answer I'm looking for. I'll do a few `EXPLAIN`s on this query to see how to optimize it for large data sets, large result tables etc. Maybe it's worthwhile to bind `results` to `questions`, so the set to acquire answers on can be narrowed down to a minimum. I'll also test whether the hydration works correctly on grouped results, but I don't see why that wouldn't work. (I probably just need to read the AR documentation on `group()`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
input = { 
  1 => 2, # Gender: female
  2 => 4  # Age:    30-65
}

answers = input.inject([]){|ary, input| ary << input[1] } # [2,4]

results = {
  "Junior man"   => [1,3],
  "Senior man"   => [1,4],
  "Old man"      => [1,5],
  "Junior woman" => [2,3],
  "Senior woman" => [2,4],
  "Old woman"    => [2,5]
}

output = results.select {|k,v| v == answers} # "Senior woman" => [2,4]

output.keys[0] # "Senior Woman"
```

Comment: I don't know whether I'm making myself totally clear in my question, but I am working with a database and ActiveRecord. I don't see how this approach could be efficient (i.e. done without either getting the selecting the entire junction table into a hash, or running a query for every possible combination for that question.

Comment: Don't worry, you did make me look up some nice documentation of Ruby's array operations, which was very useful to learn as I'm rather new to Ruby and Rails. :-)